# How to define custom default values for TYPO3's site configuration?

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

By creating a file `/Configuration/SiteConfiguration/Overrides/sites.php` in a site package, it is possible to modify default values, such as …

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3') or die();

$GLOBALS['SiteConfiguration']['site_language']['columns']['title']['config']['default'] = 'Deutsch';
$GLOBALS['SiteConfiguration']['site_language']['columns']['typo3Language']['config']['default'] = 'de';
```

..., or even [add new fields to the backend form](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/ExtendingSiteConfig.html#extending-the-form-gui).

Is it also possible to define some default values that do not appear in the backend form but are still automatically created in a new sites.yaml files?

For example, it is about the following values:

```
routeEnhancers:
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    map:
      sitemap.xml: 1533906435
settings:
  redirects:
    autoUpdateSlugs: false
    autoCreateRedirects: false
    redirectTTL: 0
    httpStatusCode: 301
```

This could allow TYPO3 admin users to create new pages with the previously defined settings without having to (or being allowed to) edit the yaml files directly.

Addendum:
I found out that the default values are set via the function [createNewBasicSite()](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/main/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Configuration/SiteConfiguration.php). Perhaps this can be extended or overwritten somehow.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to set default values, however I suggest a different solution which is possible since TYPO3 version 10.4 ([see](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.1/Feature-88742-ImportYamlFilesRelativeToTheCurrentYamlFile.html))

You can import settings from other files, which are e.g. within your site package.

```yaml
imports:
  - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Processing.yaml" }

another:
  option: true
```

Comment: But in order to enter the import, the text file must also be edited, right? I want editors with admin rights who don't know what a yaml file is and who shouldn't have direct access to it to still be able to create new sites (small sites for subdomains) via the backend. Copy and paste of existing root pages unfortunately does not duplicate the configuration.

Comment: I have just been looking for a way to "activate" your import suggestion via the backend form, e.g. with a checkbox "Import default values", but this seems to be a bit too complex to realise with the current TCA possibilities.

The default values are set via the function createNewBasicSite() in /sysext/core/Classes/Configuration/SiteConfiguration.php. Maybe I can somehow manage to overwrite this function.

Comment: I would go for a custom backend module which duplicates a page and creates the site configuration. by default the site module is something for integrators and not only admins or even editors